# Movement of a rod submitted to a shifted torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, solid-mechanics

Suppose I have a rod of mass m initially at rest, for which a torque (F1, F2) is applied at the right side during a brief time $\Delta t$, as in the schema below. The rod is not fixed to anything and not submitted to gravity or any other forces.

[image: rod torque]
Intuitively, I would say that the center of mass G would follow a circular trajectory, as pictured in gray in the schema.
But this seems to contradict what I learnt when I was young, that the acceleration of the center of mass stems from the sum of the applied exterior forces (which is zero here).
Some help to understand where I am wrong would be welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your intuition is wrong. The position of the center of mass doesn't change, and you've already explained why, i.e. for the second law of Dynamics.

The rods have an angular acceleration, given by the equation of motion for rotation of rigid bodies, whose component in the out-of-plane direction reads

$I_G  \dot{\omega} = M_G^{ext} = -F d$,

having assumed counter-clockwise rotations as positive, $I_G$ the inertia around the out-of-plane axis, $\omega$ the component of the angular velocity in the same direction, $F$ the force magnitude and $d$ the distance between the action lines of the couple of forces.

Putting together the results from the equations of motion for translation and rotation, you can assert that body starts rotating around its center of mass, whose position in space is constant.

Comment: "lying on the floor" means that the floor introduces actions, through friction, in the system. So you'd better model it if you want the mathematical system to be representative of your physical system

Comment: Maybe you don't agree with Physics this time, or if you agree with Physics the mathematical model above doesn't agree with you. No offense, but I would trust in Physics and accurate mathematical models, to be tested against accurate physical experiments, rather than your intuition

Comment: @basics The question says nothing about 'lying on the floor'.

Comment: in my comments, i was referring to @Kuhlambo comments. The orginal question is quite clear, and my answer replies to it

Comment: I'm sorry, but downvoting is a medal for you, that you can't understand and make a serious conversation about a basic problem in classical mechanics. You could raise you own question on SE physics. Let's see what the answers will be

Comment: It's the last message I send to you about it, explaining why you get an experience that doesn't not agree with the mathematical model. Your experimental setup made of a pen lying on the table is a very poor experimental setup to test the mathematical system proposed in the original question, mainly because of friction. Just have a think. Otherwise, open a question on SE

Comment: @basics There's net torque about the point $A$, which causes rotational acceleration of the rod about $A$ in the CW sense. Similarly, you can look at torque about point $B$.

Comment: @Kuhlambo friction from the floor or table doesn't really change anything much, at least not qualitatively, so you're good to go.

Comment: @Kuhlambo remember to describe your experimental set-up, including how you measure the forces you're applying (that you're not measuring in your experience now) and then someone can give you an explanation

Comment: It could be a good experiment to set up. Quite a simple physical systems, to train you in accurately measure position of a point, rotation of a body and forces applied to the system, to quantify the errors of the non ideal processes and the effects of sensors and actuators

Comment: @Kuhlambo. I can understand why basics feels bitter.  If you have tried to experiment this case, I think the problem may be you have to be very careful about the way you apply the torque to the rod: fingers are not good. Maybe a wood rod immersed in water with 2 small propellers (mounted with an elastic) to create the forces F1 and F2 may give a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: (at least if the wood rod is sufficiently heavy for the water friction to be negligible in first approximation)

Answer (score 0):

I wish to see how will the rod move in a finite amount of time, so I assumed there are two opposite charges at the two positions $A$ and $B$ with a static uniform electric field along the vertical direction filling all space. This allows one to match the initial forces exactly with the question and also to solve for the finite-time behavior.

The kinetic energy is $T=1/2 m (\dot{x}_c+\dot{y}_c)+ 1/2 I \dot{\theta}^2$, where $I$ is the moment of inertia around the center of mass and $\theta$ is the angle the rod makes with $x$ axis. The potential energy is $V=-k y_A+k y_B=k(l_B-l_A) \sin\theta$, where $l_B$ is the distance of B to the center of mass, and similarly for $l_A$.
Now the Lagrangian is
$$L=T-V.$$
Using the Euler–Lagrange equation
$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_\alpha}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_\alpha}=0$,
one can get the equations for $x_c$, $y_c$, $\theta$:
$$\frac{d ^2 x_c}{d t^2}=0$$
$$\frac{d ^2 y_c}{d t^2}=0$$
$$I \frac{d ^2 \theta}{d t^2}=-k(l_B-l_A) \cos\theta.$$
From the first two one can see that if the center of mass is initially at rest, it will remain so.
From the third one can solve for $\theta(t)$, which can be done numerically. The bottom line is, the rod rotates with its center of mass being at rest the whole time.

I confess that even after deriving and solving these equations I still find it counter-intuitive.

Comment: So, you introduce electric charges inside an E field to be able to use a potential energy in the context of analytical mechanics during a brief time. You are a real fan of analytical mechanics, aren't you  :-)

Comment: But I think the simplest and the best answer is that of basics. Since it has been unduly downvoted, I demand other persons to upvote it.